# Maven dependencies complaining jars files are missing in .m2 repository, but jar files are inplace

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

Maven dependencies complaining that few jars files are missing for ex: 
cucumber-junit, cucumber-jave, surefile-plugin
but these are in place , these jar present in .m2 repository.

Please let me know , if anyone can help me

I have added cucumber plugin in eclipse.

I did Maven -update, Maven clean but nothing is solving issue

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml

Comment: Assuming the problem is not in your dependencies, you can delete them from local repo, as they will be re-downloaded. I do get an occasional corrupt archive, which might cause this (or open them and test to see if the archive is corrupt)

Comment: It resolved, the problem was Windows->Preferences->Maven->UserSettings was pointing wrong xml file.